# I need to Convert video format to Codec: H264-MPEG-4 AVC in java.This video format will support to all latest html 5 browsers

Tags: h.264, mpeg-4, jcodec

I need to convert video format to Codec:- H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1) .
This video format will support to all latest html 5 browsers.

I need help to solve this issue If any one having the code please post the code  Thank you in Advance.

I already tried Below code to make video. But it codec format Motion jpeg video it is not support to play Html 5 Browser.

```
 package com.screencapture;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import javax.media.Buffer;
    import javax.media.ConfigureCompleteEvent;
    import javax.media.ControllerEvent;
    import javax.media.ControllerListener;
    import javax.media.DataSink;
    import javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent;
    import javax.media.Format;
    import javax.media.Manager;
    import javax.media.MediaLocator;
    import javax.media.PrefetchCompleteEvent;
    import javax.media.Processor;
    import javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent;
    import javax.media.ResourceUnavailableEvent;
    import javax.media.Time;
    import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
    import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkErrorEvent;
    import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkEvent;
    import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkListener;
    import javax.media.datasink.EndOfStreamEvent;
    import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
    import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
    import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
    import javax.media.protocol.FileTypeDescriptor;
    import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferDataSource;
    import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferStream;

    /**
     * This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into a
     * QuickTime movie.
     */
    public class JpegImagesToMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

        public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector inFiles,MediaLocator outML) throws MalformedURLException {
            ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate,inFiles);

            Processor p;

            try {
                //System.err
                //      .println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
                p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
                return false;
            }

            p.addControllerListener(this);

            // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
            // some processing options on the processor.
            p.configure();
            if (!waitForState(p, p.Configured)) {
                System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
                return false;
            }

            // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
            p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(
                    FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

            // Query for the processor for supported formats.
            // Then set it on the processor.
            TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
            Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
            if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
                System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: "
                        + tcs[0].getFormat());
                return false;
            }

            tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

            //System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

            // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
            // realize it.
            p.realize();
            if (!waitForState(p, p.Realized)) {
                System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
                return false;
            }

            // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
            DataSink dsink;
            if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
                System.err.println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                                + outML);
                return false;
            }

            dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
            fileDone = false;

            System.out.println("Generating the video : "+outML.getURL().toString());

            // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
            try {
                p.start();

                dsink.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IO error during processing");
                return false;
            }

            // Wait for EndOfStream event.
            waitForFileDone();

            // Cleanup.
            try {
                dsink.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            p.removeControllerListener(this);

            System.out.println("Video creation completed!!!!!");
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Create the DataSink.
         */
        DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

            DataSource ds;

            if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
                System.err.println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
                return null;
            }

            DataSink dsink;

            try {
                //System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
                dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
                dsink.open();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
                return null;
            }

            return dsink;
        }

        Object waitSync = new Object();
        boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

        /**
         * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state. Return
         * false if the transition failed.
         */
        boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                try {
                    while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                        waitSync.wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return stateTransitionOK;
        }

        /**
         * Controller Listener.
         */
        public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

            if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
                    || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
                    || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
                synchronized (waitSync) {
                    stateTransitionOK = true;
                    waitSync.notifyAll();
                }
            } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
                synchronized (waitSync) {
                    stateTransitionOK = false;
                    waitSync.notifyAll();
                }
            } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
                evt.getSourceController().stop();
                evt.getSourceController().close();
            }
        }

        Object waitFileSync = new Object();
        boolean fileDone = false;
        boolean fileSuccess = true;

        /**
         * Block until file writing is done.
         */
        boolean waitForFileDone() {
            synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                try {
                    while (!fileDone)
                        waitFileSync.wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return fileSuccess;
        }

        /**
         * Event handler for the file writer.
         */
        public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

            if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
                synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                    fileDone = true;
                    waitFileSync.notifyAll();
                }
            } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
                synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                    fileDone = true;
                    fileSuccess = false;
                    waitFileSync.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }



        static void prUsage() {
            System.err
                    .println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie -w <width> -h <height> -f <frame rate> -o <output URL> <input JPEG file 1> <input JPEG file 2> ...");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        /* Create a media locator from the given string. */
        static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {
            System.out.println("url:"+url);

            MediaLocator ml;

            if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
                return ml;

            if (url.startsWith(File.separator)){
                System.out.println("if::");
                if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
                    return ml;
            } else {
                System.out.println("else::");
                String file = "file:C://ScreenRec/"+ url;
                if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
                    return ml;
            }

            return null;
        }
        // Inner classes.

        /*
          A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and turn that into a
          stream of JMF buffers. The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
         */
        class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

            ImageSourceStream streams[];

            ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector images) {
                streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
                streams[0] = new ImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
            }

            public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
            }

            public MediaLocator getLocator() {
                return null;
            }

            /*
              Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video frames
              without a container format.
             */
            public String getContentType() {
                return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
            }

            public void connect() {
            }

            public void disconnect() {
            }

            public void start() {
            }

            public void stop() {
            }

            /* Return the ImageSourceStreams.*/
            public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
                return streams;
            }

            /* We could have derived the duration from the number of frames and
              frame rate. But for the purpose of this program, it's not necessary.
             */
            public Time getDuration() {
                return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
            }

            public Object[] getControls() {
                return new Object[0];
            }

            public Object getControl(String type) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /* The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource. */
        class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

            Vector images;
            int width, height;
            VideoFormat format;

            int nextImage = 0; // index of the next image to be read.
            boolean ended = false;

            public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                    Vector images) {
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.images = images;

                format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, new Dimension(width,
                        height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray,
                        (float) frameRate);
            }

            /*
              We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
             */
            public boolean willReadBlock() {
                return false;
            }

            /*
              This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth of video
              data.
             */
            public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

                // Check if we've finished all the frames.
                if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                    // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                    //System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                    buf.setEOM(true);
                    buf.setOffset(0);
                    buf.setLength(0);
                    ended = true;
                    return;
                }

                String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
                nextImage++;

                //System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

                // Open a random access file for the next image.
                RandomAccessFile raFile;
                raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

                byte data[] = null;

                // Check the input buffer type & size.

                if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
                    data = (byte[]) buf.getData();

                // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
                if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
                    data = new byte[(int) raFile.length()];
                    buf.setData(data);
                }

                // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
                raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int) raFile.length());

                //System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

                buf.setOffset(0);
                buf.setLength((int) raFile.length());
                buf.setFormat(format);
                buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | buf.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

                // Close the random access file.
                raFile.close();
            }

            /*
              Return the format of each video frame. That will be JPEG.
             */
            public Format getFormat() {
                return format;
            }

            public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
                return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
            }

            public long getContentLength() {
                return 0;
            }

            public boolean endOfStream() {
                return ended;
            }

            public Object[] getControls() {
                return new Object[0];
            }

            public Object getControl(String type) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you must add multi choice to be cross browser source video need to serve webm ogv mp4 in the good orders